# Jenkins get variable GIT_URL is not available if "Skip default checkout" is marked

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

If I set in Jenkinsfile:

```
options { skipDefaultCheckout() }
```

then in steps in pipeline below, variable `${env.GIT_URL}` appeared do not available. For example cannot complete step:

```
stage('Clean checkout') {
            steps {
                checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: "master"]],
                         userRemoteConfigs: [[url: "${env.GIT_URL}"]]])
            }
        }
```

in this step variable `${env.GIT_URL}` = *null* due to build console log.

But if you enable back default checkout, so delete:

```
options { skipDefaultCheckout() }
```

Then `${env.GIT_URL}` became available. Is it expected behaviour? I cannot see [Git plugin variables](https://plugins.jenkins.io/git/#environment-variables) in Pipeline where disabled declarative checkout?

Comment: Is your Jenkinsfile a part of some git repository, or is it just pasted as text?

Comment: Part of repository.

Comment: Something depend of this?

Comment: It's interesting, I'm seeing something similar on two of our projects. One started as a simple Jenkinsfile without skipDefaultCheckout, and we built it like that for a bit, and then a co-worker decided to complicate things a bit and added skipDefaultCheckout and explicit checkout; in that context, GIT_URL works. In another project that started with skipDefaultCheckout from the start, I'm not able to access GIT_URL (I'm trying from a NonCPS function in both cases).

Comment: I've created a Jira ticket for Jenkins team usin the information from this question. I've encountered same issue. https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-66803

Comment: @Dziki_Jam Awesome! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the expected behavior. Source: https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-66803?focusedCommentId=414193&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-414193

Answer (score 0):

In our Jenkinsfile, we have

```
    options {
        skipDefaultCheckout true
    }

    environment {
        GIT_URL = 'git@github.com:mycompany/myproject.git'
    }
```

After this, the variable `GIT_URL` is available and populated.

Comment: Can you show how you reference on GIT_URL in Jenkinsfile below?

Comment: Updated my answer. We drop it in.

Comment: Make sense then, if you define it in environment))